# Latest Windows version that officially supports Office 97?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

I need to fire up an ancient legacy database that runs within Access '97 and that isn't compatible with any later version of Microsoft Office.

What's the latest version of Microsoft Windows on which Access '97 can be installed?

Comment: I don't know, but a reasonable thing to try is spin up a Windows 7 VM and attempt to install it as is.  If that doesn't work, attempt to install in compatibility mode for '98 and perhaps run in compatibility mode for '98.

Comment: Google knows....https://www.google.com/search?q=Office+97+and+windows+7&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS771US771&oq=Office+97+and+windows+7&aqs=chrome..69i57.7911j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Virtual machines to the rescue, right!!

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 4.0 or later with Service Pack 2 (SP2) or later

> ### MS Office Products for Windows
>
> This section describes Office 97 packages for Windows.
>
> ...
>
> #### MS Office 97 Professional Edition
>
> Microsoft Office 97 Professional Edition includes all the programs in the Standard Edition plus Microsoft Access 97.
>
> **System Requirements**
>
> To use Microsoft Office 97 Professional Edition, you need:
>
> - A personal computer with a 486 or higher processor.
>
>   One of the following operating systems:
>
>   - Microsoft Windows 95.
>
>     – or –
>   - Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 3.51 or later with Service Pack 5. (Office 97 does not run on earlier versions of Windows.)
>
>     – or –
>   - Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 4.0 or later with Service Pack 2 (SP2) or later.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749816.aspx

Comment: I rather suspect that document pre-dates the release of e.g. Windows 2000, and therefore only documents the supported O/Ses _at the time of release_.

Comment: this Microsoft link talks about an issue with UAC caused by installing Office 97 on Windows 7 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/978591/you-cannot-change-user-account-control-uac-settings-on-windows-7

Comment: I'm not sure what counts as "official support". It says Office 97 causes a registry issue on Windows 7 but seeing as Microsoft addressed it, perhaps that is official support.

Comment: I know Office 97 worked well on Windows 2000, but also that it could have issues on XP. I would therefor say office 97 works on 95, NT4, 98, ME, 2K

Comment: It's odd that MS have a page saying which versions of Office will work with Windows 10, but I can find no similar page for older versions of Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Office 97 should work in Windows 10. See the link below for a video showing someone installing and running it on a Windows 10 system: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCqU-z7TcYc

Edit: I just saw that you edited your question to include "officially". I'm not sure what Microsoft would recommend about installing Office 97 on newer Windows versions, I only have anecdotal evidence of it seeming to work on Windows 10.

Comment: yeah, sorry about that clarification.   Officially, Microsoft say it's not supported under Windows 10 - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/which-versions-of-office-work-with-windows-10-0fc85c97-da69-466e-b2b4-54f7d7275705